# Computer restarted automatically in loop during boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, bios

I have Dell optiplex 990 computer. I just re- install windows 7 ultimate because of some virus infections.
Windows installed with no error. But after restarting computer, when windows logo appears computer restarted automatically.
I installed windows several times but same result.
I remove the hdd from this computer and insert into onother computer that I have. At that computer windows install and computer boots normal.
Then I tried to boot Dell computer with same hdd, but computer unable to boot and goes into reboot loop.
I checked the bios settings. The sata operation is set on raid- on. I changed it to ahci. And install the windows but same fault.
Then I load default settings in bios and repeat installation by same fault.
Can someone help me?

Comment: It looks like a hardware problem to me.

Comment: Yes "Zoran". It's strange that the system have two ddr3 ram, each of 2 gb. When I connect single one in motherboard, the system is ok. But when both of them connect, system doesn't start.

Comment: Have you tried running some memory test?

Comment: How to run such tests?

Comment: Download [Hiren’s BootCD 15.2](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/files/Hirens.BootCD.15.2.zip), burn the image on CD/DVD, or mount the image on USB drive with [Rufus](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.12/rufus-3.12.exe), or some other tool, and run Memtest86+.

Comment: Will I  boot the system from this hiren's bootcd 15.2 burned cd?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Boot the Hiren's BootCD, and run memtest.